# Eth-gas-reporter typeError

Tags: truffle, ganache, gas-price, truffle-test

I am trying to understand how the eth-gas-reporter works but I keep getting
 `TypeError: invalid reporter 'eth-gas-reporter'` when I ran `truffle test`.

Specifically the output is:

```
Using network 'development'.

TypeError: invalid reporter 'eth-gas-reporter'
    at createInvalidReporterError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/errors.js:101:13)
    at Mocha.reporter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:305:13)
    at new Mocha (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:143:6)
    at Object.createMocha (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/Test.js:186:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/Test.js:70:1)
    at prepareConfigAndRunTests (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/test/prepareConfigAndRunTests.js:12:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/test/run.js:128:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.5.4 (core: 5.5.4)
Node v16.13.1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the truffle-config file? Could you check if upgrading/downgrading fixes the problem?